# Is there canonical reference linking the original Cyberdyne Systems research in T2 to Brewster's Skynet in T3?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet

Is there **canonical** reference to show that the original Cyberdyne Systems research in T2 (which was presumably destroyed by teenage John and Sarah Connor, Miles Dyson and T-800) somehow helped or influenced Robert Brewster's building of military Skynet system in T3?

Comment: What would count? A reference or visual of the T-800's CPU?

Comment: Its was said by T-850 in T3 or, Marcus Wright saw it in Skynet information network in Salvation.

Comment: @JohnO - Anything (your example included) that references canon

Comment: @SachinShekhar I don't think his remark counts. Arnie seemed to be operating under the assumption that history from the previous loop still applied, he seemed to think Skynet might be de-activatable, for instance. Just as Connor himself believed. DVK: I can't even think of what might count, other than my first two examples, but despite not having recently watched the movie I'm pretty sure neither is there.

Answer (score 4):

In T3, upon being asked how he exists, T-850 told:

> After the destruction of the company's headquarters, Cyberdyne Systems patents are obtained by the U.S. Government, with another technological corporation Cyber Research Systems. Skynet continues to be developed by the company for SAC-NORAD,and ultimately, Judgment Day occurs, just at a later date than it would have originally.

In *Terminator Salvation*, it was displayed that Dr. Serena Kogan from Cyberdyne Systems convinced Marcus Wright to donate his body for research in 2003. In 2018, Marcus saw a news while connected with Skynet that Cyberdyne Systems was sold to US Airforce. And, Dr. Serena's visual from Skynet side says that Dr. Serena was also behind development of Skynet.

Comment: I think that this is a pretty concise treatment of what happened.  T:3 and T:Salvation do offer brief explanations of what happened to Cyberdyne after the events of T:2.  It's made clear enough in those movies that Cyberdyne's original research was picked up by the government - and it is the Air Force which developed the AI form that research.  How much of it was originally Cyberdyne's is still unknown.